# Resize/Change Figure Axis Range in Matlab

Tags: matlab, resize, matlab-figure, figure, axes

I have a button in my Matlab GUI to open up an axes plot in a new figure, here is my code:

```
fig=figure;
set(fig, 'Position', [100, 100, 1049, 895]);
h=handles.axes2;
copyobj(h,fig); 
set(gca,'units','pix') 

set(gca,'units','norm')
```

However, the axes is quite small in the new figure:

[image]

But when I try to add this line at the bottom of the previous code:

```
    set(gca,{'Position',[100, 100, 1049, 895]}); % [left bottom right top]
```

nothing changes... I have tried changing the numbers as well but the axes does not get resized...

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Nothing changes because the values are exactly the same ones, right?

Comment: No I just put those numbers in as an example, I previously tried different numbers but nothing changed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use axis command :

```
% whatever code you have 
plot(x,y,'-o');
% now add limits for the axisX and axisY 
% that combined with the position limit should zoom your picture automatically
% x1, x2, y1, y2 should be actual values like 0.5, 1, -4 etc. whatever you find appropriate
% if it doesnt zoom as you expect - remove the Position setting and see how it looks.
axis([x1 x2 y1 y2]);
```

for more info see example from the matlab site: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axis.html

Comment: thanks for your answer, any idea how to put this into my code?

Answer (score 1):

Just for more information, there are other functions called [xlim](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlim.html) and [ylim](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ylim.html) They can set the axis individually and the nice thing is that they can autoscale.

For example you want to zoom in on x=10 o 100, but don't know what y values to expect. As you know the axis command needs `axis([xmin xmax ymin ymax])` but if you simply do

```
xmin = 10;
xmax = 100;
xlim([xmin, xmax]);
```

this will zoom in to the appropriate X, and it will autoscale Y to the appropriate size.

Comment: thank you that's something that will come in handy for me as well :)